# Проброс вебинтерфейса из внешки в локальную сеть

Tags: сеть, маршрутизация, роутер

Сразу скажу далек от сетей
Подскажите можно ли пробросить веб интерфейс по следующей схеме

Есть офис в котором крутится веб интерфейс 192.168.0.220 в сети 192.168.0.1/24, к этой сети подключен роутер на котором висит ВПН клиент с подсетью 192.168.10.1/24.

Есть ли возможность посадить веб интерфейс 192.168.0.220 вместо веб интерфейса роутера 192.168.10.1

Comment: У вас по ссылке http://192.168.10.1 веб-интерфейс роутера открывается? Тогда только если вашу вебнюшечку повесить на отличный от 80-го порт, например, 8080 на роутере, и с этого порта сделать DNAT на 192.168.0.220:80

Comment: От роутера зависит. в некоторых можно поменять порт на котором висит web самого роутера и тогда 80 можно будет пробросить. Либо просто попробовать написать правило проброса, оно может и так сработать, но тогда вы потеряете доступ к настройкам роутера.

Comment: а можно пример привести как делается dnat

Comment: @EugeneTatmyanin как это настраивать в конкретном роутере (через веб-интерфейс), зависит от конкретного роутера. В "понятиях" iptables это можно написать, например, так: `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.220:80`